# Rolling Year Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas

Hello, I have the following code:

```
# Import Libraies
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Conect to Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Read Data
ruta = '/content/drive/MyDrive/example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(ruta)
df.head(15)

d = pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01",end="2022-01-01", freq='MS')
dates = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":d})
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"]) 
df_merge = pd.merge(dates, df, how='outer', on='DATE')
```

The data that I am using, you could download here: [DATA](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHNuHbWUL6FUqaAQGmjXlSITtHKrILgV/view?usp=sharing)

What I am trying to achieve is something known as `Rolling Year`.
First I create this metric gruped for each category:

```
# ROLLING YEAR

##################################################################################################

# I want to make a Roling Year for each category. Thats mean how much sell each category since 12 moths ago TO current month

# RY_ACTUAL One year have 12 months so I pass as parameter in the rolling 12
f = lambda x:x.rolling(12).sum()
df_merge["RY_ACTUAL"]  = df_merge.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f)

# RY_24 I create a rolling with 24 as parameter to compare actual RY vs last RY
f_1 = lambda x:x.rolling(24).sum()
df_merge["RY_24"]  = df_merge.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f_1)

#RY_LAST Substract RY_24 - RY_Actual to get the correct amount. Thats mean amount of RY vs the amount of RY-1
df_merge["RY_LAST"]  = df_merge["RY_24"] - df_merge["RY_ACTUAL"]


##################################################################################################

df_merge.head(30)
```

And it works perfectly, ´cause if you download the file and then filter for example for "`Blue`" category, you could see, something like this:

[image]

Thats mean, if you stop in the row `2015-November`, you could see in the column `RY_ACTUAL` the sum of all the values 12 records before.

Mi next goal is to create a similar column using the `rollig` function but with the next condition:

> The column must sum all the sales of ALL the categories, as long as
> the `Color/Animal` column is equal to `Colour`. For example if I am
> stopped in `2016-December`, it should give me the sum of ALL the sales
> of the colors from `2016-January to 2016-December`

This was my attempt:

```
df_merge.loc[(df_merge['Colour/Animal'] == 'Colour'),'Sales'].apply(f)
```

Cold anyone help me to code correctly this example?.

Thanks in advance comunity!!!

Comment: I think you only need to create a new df, by filtering away the lines where it is `'Colour'`, and do the rolling sum things on the new df. e.g. `new_df = df[df['Color/Animal'] == 'Colour']`

Comment: Raymond, thank you very much for your comment. I start with the idea and I think almost got it. Sometime we are so tired that didn´t se the answer in front of us. Again Thanks!